# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string month(),year()

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have these data:

```
Col1             Col2  Col3
2014-12-31        Q     
2014-12-10        Q


CREATE TABLE Persons
(
    Col1 varchar(50),
    Col2 varchar(50),
    Col3 varchar(20)
); 

INSERT INTO Persons(Col1, Col2,Col3) 
VALUES ('2014-12-20', 'Q','');

INSERT INTO Persons(Col1, Col2,Col3) 
VALUES ('2014-12-10', 'Q','');
```

I run this query:

```
select 
  convert(date, Col1,104) as Col1,
  Col2,
  case when Col2 = 'Q' then convert(nvarchar(10),year(Col1)+'Q0')
  end as Col3
from Persons
```

I get this error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Comment: Do not you mean `year(Col4)` instead of `year(Col1)`?

Comment: Any reason you aren't using `date`? The best way to avoid conversion problems is to use the proper type.

Comment: yes, I 'm sorry, I fix it.

Comment: Also, 104 is the *German* format `dd.mm.yyyy`. The safest string format to represent dates is the *unseparated ISO format* `yyyymmdd`. The style code is 112.

Comment: Why not try as `convert(date, Col1) as Col1,`

Comment: Your problem starts and ends with your decision to store dates in an nvarchar column. use the proper data type for your data, and your problem will be solved.

Comment: I tried that but nothing has changed.

Comment: @CoderofCode this isn't guaranteed to work. The unambiguous *date* style is the unseparated ISO style. The dashed ODBC or ISO8601 styles include both date and time.

Comment: Tried what? What didn't work? Just use a `date`-typed column and forget about conversions

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE  @P TABLE
(

    Col1 varchar(50),
    Col2 varchar(50),
    Col3 varchar(20)
) 

  INSERT INTO @P(Col1, Col2,Col3)    
  VALUES ('2014-12-20', 'Q','');

  INSERT INTO @P(Col1, Col2,Col3)    
  VALUES ('2014-12-10', 'Q','');

select 
  convert(varchar(10), Col1,104) as Col1,
  Col2,
  case when Col2 = 'Q' then
    RIGHT(convert(nvarchar(10),year(Col1),106),5) + 'Q0'
  end as Col3    
from @P
```

OUTPUT:

[image]

Comment: Please format your answer appropriately. To enter code, just add four spaces at the beginning. Also, how does this differ from all other answers?

Comment: After editing, I see that you *don't* convert the text to a date but convert the varchar(50) field to a varchar(10) field. I doubt that's what the OP wanted. Anyway, you don't need to use convert, just return `Col1` as is. Using a style to convert the result of `year` (an int) to varchar is also a noop. A simple cast(year(Col1) as varchar(4)) is enough

Answer (score 0):

Your error is caused by:

1. `convert(date, Col1, 104)`

Note that `104` is `dd.mm.yyyy`. `'2014-12-20'` will result in an error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

You need to `cast` it to `date` first then `convert` to `varchar`:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST('2014-12-20' AS DATE), 104)
```

which outputs: `20.12.2014`.

2. `convert(nvarchar(10),year(Col1)+'Q0')`

You should convert `year(Col1)` to `varchar` first before concatenating `'Q0'`.

Your final query should be:

```
SELECT
    CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), CAST(Col1 AS DATE), 104) AS Col1,
    Col2,
    CASE 
        WHEN Col2 = 'Q' THEN CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4), YEAR(Col1)) + 'Q0')
    END AS Col3
FROM Persons
```

---

*You should also convert `Col1` to `DATE` first before calling `YEAR()`*. As stated in the comments, the problem starts when you decided to store dates in a `nvarchar` column. The `CAST` to `DATE` will still error out if the `Col1` is an invalid date.

Comment: what about this query i wrote before:                                                        select 
  convert(date, Col1,104) as Col1,
   Col2,
   case when Col2 = 'Q' then 
     case when month(Col1) in (10,11,12) then convert(nvarchar(10),year(Col1)+'Q0')
 end as Col3
from Persons

Answer (score 0):

I see there 2 problems. First one is with convert to concrete date format from varchar. At the first , convert it only in to date format. Then use concrete format.
Problem number 2 is in Col3. At the first you must convert year on the varchar, then use + with string.
Solution:

```
select 
  CONVERT(DATE,convert(date, Col1),104) as Col1,
  Col2,
  case when Col2 = 'Q' then convert(nvarchar(10),year(Col1))+'Q0'
  end as Col3
from Persons
```

or

```
select 
  CONVERT(DATE,convert(date, Col1),104) as Col1,
  Col2,
  case when Col2 = 'Q' then convert(nvarchar(10),year(Col1))+'Q0'
  end as Col3
from Persons
WHERE isdate(Col1) = 1
```

Comment: How will this change anything? 104 is the dot-separated German style. If the first conversion works, what is the point of the second conversion?

Comment: Consider that the type of columns is varchar i made a mistake.

Comment: or you can use cast, used in answer of wewesthemenace

Comment: convert(date, Col1,104) as Col1   only this is working for Col1. I have tried all solution but I got an error.

Comment: yes, I run also only the select  CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), CAST(Col1 AS DATE), 104) AS Col1  and gives me error: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Comment: Why do you insist on using VARCHAR and an ambiguous text format? CAST will use the column's collation if it can't guess. There's no date style for `yyyy-mm-dd`. If you *have* to use varchar, store `20140220`